# Tornado Request Handler fine tuning

Tags: tornado

I have a 404 Request handler which handles situations like http://host:port/mycompany. Here is the code for that.

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", HomeHandler),
            (r"/mycompany", myCompanyHandler),
        ]
        super(Application, self).__init__(handlers,     default_handler_class=my404Handler)

class myBaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        def write_error(self, status_code, **kwargs):
                if status_code == 404:
                        self.render("404.html")
                else:
                        self.render("genericerror.html")

class my404Handler(myBaseHandler):
    def prepare(self):
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(404)

class HomeHandler(myBaseHandler):
    def get(self):
            self.render("home.html")

class myCompanyHandler(myBaseHandler):
etc
etc
etc
```

I would like to also display a 404 page when user enters http://host:port/mycompany/ (notice the front slash at the end). What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: This looks correct to me. What are you getting instead of a 404? `myCompanyHandler`? `genericerror.html`?

Comment: Well, I might have got it wrong. Sorry about that. http://host:port/myCompanyHandler/ works fine with a proper 404 error. But http://host:port/myCompanyHandler (no slash) goes to myCompanyHandler and gets trapped in my argument check routine (code not shown above) and throws an error of Incorrect parameter. I would like ..../myCompanyHandler to through a 404 message as well. Can I?

Comment: Yes, just catch the "incorrect parameter" error and raise an `HTTPError(404)` instead.